# My animation is stuck only at the first image android studio

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner and this is my source for my java class

```
ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    if (i == null) throw new AssertionError();
    i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.source);



    AnimationDrawable pro = (AnimationDrawable)i.getDrawable();
```

Comment: Please add some details what issue you are facing?

Comment: so my app is loading and no error....but in the image view instead of the gif...the starting point alone is seen....and its not moving

Comment: How do you tell it to start?

Comment: if i use pro.start()...i get the following message.....Attempt to invoke virtual method.....'void android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.start()' on a null object reference......